# Get a calculated price from Product Variation

Tags: commerce

I created a promotion with offer type - `Fixed amount off each matching product` and applies to - `Specific product`. In my custom block I get the product entity and try to get the calculated price via `commerce_order.price_calculator` service.

```
commercePriceCalc = \Drupal::service('commerce_order.price_calculator');
$context = new Context(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load(1), 
                     \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_store')->load(1));
$prices = $commercePriceCalc->calculate($slide->field_product->entity, 1, $context);
```

So, `calculate` method returns me a `PriceCalculatorResult` object with 2 properties, `calculatedPrice` and `basePrice` but they are identical.

```
PriceCalculatorResult {#3311 ▼
  #calculatedPrice: Price {#3310 ▼
    #number: "1000.000000"
    #currencyCode: "UAH"
  }
  #basePrice: Price {#3310 ▼
    #number: "1000.000000"
    #currencyCode: "UAH"
  }
  #adjustments: []
}
```

As if the discount didn't apply.

Comment: According to the result, the discount definitely did not apply. Does it actually apply when you add the product to the cart?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have already solved this issue, check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem, by passing the 4th argument `$adjustment_types` to the `$commercePriceCalc->calculate` method.

```
$adjustment_types = array("promotion" => "promotion");
```

So, the final version of the code

```
$commercePriceCalc = \Drupal::service('commerce_order.price_calculator');
$context = new Context(\Drupal::currentUser(), 
                     \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_store')->load($store_id));
$prices = $commercePriceCalc->calculate($slide->field_product->entity, 1, $context, $adjustment_types);
```